# Select first row with a particular category present in a column of the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am having trouble doing this operation. I want to select the dataframe rows  that have the first BG tag for every rider.

```
data = [{'rider': 'x1', 'quarter':'q1' , 'tag':BB},
 {'rider': 'x1', 'quarter':'q2' , 'tag':BG},
 {'rider': 'x1', 'quarter':'q3' , 'tag':BB},
 {'rider': 'x2', 'quarter':'q1' , 'tag':BG},
 {'rider': 'x2', 'quarter':'q2' , 'tag':BB},
{'rider': 'x2', 'quarter':'q3' , 'tag':BB},
 {'rider': 'x2', 'quarter':'q4' , 'tag':BG},
{'rider': 'x3', 'quarter':'q1' , 'tag':BB},
 {'rider': 'x3', 'quarter':'q2' , 'tag':BB},
 {'rider': 'x3', 'quarter':'q3' , 'tag':BG},
  {'rider': 'x3', 'quarter':'q4' , 'tag':BG}
 ] 

 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

for every rider, I want to select the row with tag BG but only the row when the tag appears for the first time. 
I have tried subsetting and doing some groupby operations but they have not helped.

```
 O/P:
{'rider': 'x1', 'quarter':'q2' , 'tag':BG}
{'rider': 'x2', 'quarter':'q1' , 'tag':BG}
{'rider': 'x3', 'quarter':'q3' , 'tag':BG}
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
df.loc[df.tag=='BG'].drop_duplicates('rider')
Out[556]: 
  rider quarter tag
1    x1      q2  BG
3    x2      q1  BG
9    x3      q3  BG
```

For the `dict`

```
d=df.loc[df.tag=='BG'].drop_duplicates('rider').to_dict('r')
d
Out[559]: 
[{'quarter': 'q2', 'rider': 'x1', 'tag': 'BG'},
 {'quarter': 'q1', 'rider': 'x2', 'tag': 'BG'},
 {'quarter': 'q3', 'rider': 'x3', 'tag': 'BG'}]
```